# How to create a Spark DF as below

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to create a Scala Spark DF as below. This question may be silly but need to know what is the best approach to create small structures for testing purpose

1. For creating a minimal DF.
2. For creating a minimal RDD.

I've tried the following code so far without success :

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("7","8","9"))
```

and then creating to DF by

```
val dfSchema = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

and

```
 rdd2.toDF(dfSchema: _*)
```

Here's a sample Dataframe I'd like to obtain :

```
c1  c2  c3
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Comment: Hi @abc_spark, can you specify both your use cases and what you've tried to do so far (not working or inefficient code for instance) ? Is that for testing applications with minimal Dataframes / RDDs ?

Comment: This is for a testing for another usecase.I have tried with val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq("7","8","9")) and then creating to DF by val dfSchema = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3") and rdd2.map(_.toDF(dfSchema: _*). But it was not creating three columns and ended up in error

Comment: Also, when I tried creating DF directly, I should be using multiple withColumns and Unions. So wanted to know what is the best and efficient approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abc_spark, here's a sample you can use to easily create Dataframes and RDDs for testing :

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
      (1, 2, 3),
      (4, 5, 6)
    ).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

df.show(false)

+---+---+---+
|c1 |c2 |c3 |
+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |
|4  |5  |6  |
+---+---+---+

val rdd: RDD[Row] = df.rdd

rdd.map{_.getAs[Int]("c2")}.foreach{println}
```

Gives

```
5
2
```

Comment: or use case classes instead of tuples, then you can just to `toDF()` without listing all the column names

Comment: You can use case classes as suggested by @RaphaelRoth but it adds some extra boilerplate. Could be useful anyway if you want to work with strongly typed RDDs.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one "()" in Seq. Use it as below:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("7","8","9"))).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

scala> df.show
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   7|   8|   9|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Hey @Nikk, be careful your rdd2 is a DataFrame :)